# Load json key file as env in VSCode Launch Config

Tags: environment-variables, vscode-debugger

I usually set my environment variable in PowerShell using the following:

```
$env:GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = (Get-Content C:\Users\Name\Downloads\keyname.json)
```

and I cannot find a way to do this via the launch config.

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: functions framework",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "functions_framework",
            "args": [
                "--target=main",
                "--debug"
            ],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/functions/api",
            "env": {
                "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS": ????,
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a pre-launch task to run that command to extract the JSON field to a `.env` file (add a `preLaunchTask` field to your launch config and [define a task in your tasks.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) that does the extraction), and then put the path to that `.env` file in the `envFile` field of your launch config (Ex. `"envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env"`).